# How to color points in a different color if a data attribute is not null

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have a scatter plot in R (with ggplot2). The data has a numeric column (let's call it `bin`) which can contain various integer values or null.

I would like to colour the points with non-null bin values differently from the others. I do not want to one colour per value of bin, that would be too noisy. Just simply, say, red for those with a non-null bin and black for the others.

qplot has a `colour` attribute, but I don't know how to express a condition like `colour = bin != null ? "red" : "black"`

Comment: I think you mean missing, not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define the color first:

```
color <- rep("black", length(bin))
color[is.null(color)] <- "red"
```

Otherwise you can use an ifelse statement:

```
colour=ifelse(is.null(bin), "red", "black")
```

Comment: The first approach worked with one modification: using is.na instead of is.null

One minor comment is that R is not interpreting the colour literals (i.e. "red" as colour red and "black" as black) but does the autocolouring by value so two other hues end up in the chart. I guess this is fixable if I read more on the syntax.

Comment: Try `+ scale_colour_identity()`