# r - change colors of data points in a scatterplot

Tags: r, datapoint

I am learning R and working with the Default dataset. My attempt is to graphically show a relationship between balance, income, and default cases. I have managed to put together a graph and now need assistance with coloring specific points.

Note: Please excuse me if this topic has been discussed before. I looked in the forum for a similar post but failed to find one.

Here is my code:

```
dataset(Default)

plot(Default$balance~Default$income, col=Default$student, las=1, xlab = "Income",
    ylab="Balance", main="Income and balance effects on default     
    loans",pch=as.numeric(Default$default), cex = 0.7)

legend("topright",legend=unique(Default$default), title = "Default?", pch = c(1,2))
```

Could a member help me:

1. assign a different color to those which default (triangles in the graph)
2. create 2 legends: one which shows the division of the population (either a student or not), and the second which lists that triangles represent those who defaulted and circles do the same for those who did not.

Edit: The Default dataset is in the ISLR package. Thank you @ richard for pointing this out.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have `Default` in my base data sets.  Is it in a package?

Comment: Item 1: Read ?points to find out which of the five triangles you are using. (If you are colouring them you probably want pch = 17, 24, or 25). Then use `plot(..., col = ifelse(Default$default == x, "red", "black"), ...)` where `x` is the pch for the triangle you are colouring.

Comment: @Richard: Thanks for looking into this. It is not a separate package. It is one of the preloaded datasets on my R studio version 3.0.3.

Comment: Well, I can make an attempt with a different data set I guess.  It'll be the same in theory. Looks like `Default` data is in the ISLR package

Comment: @Dale: The plot function finds the triangle by default when I use pch=a.numeric(Default$default). The gap in my logic is how to color these symbols separately. I looked over your suggestion about using the if/else but don't completely grasp your logic (I am new and learning). If else is a constraint so why use a constraint function when the graph always displays all points?

Comment: @Dale I found another post with more details on the ifelse path ((http://stackoverflow.com/a/2376045/3988519))and I was able to get the right results. Thank you for your help. You can add this as an answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for others to reference:

```
plot(Default$balance~Default$income, col=ifelse(Default$default == "Yes", "green",     
Default$student), las=1, xlab = "Income", ylab="Balance", main="Income and balance 
effects on default loans",pch=as.numeric(Default$default), cex = 0.7)

legend("topright",legend=unique(Default$default), title = "Default?", pch = c(1,2), 
col = c("black", "green"))

legend("topleft", legend=unique(Default$student), title = "Student?", 
col=c("black", "red"), pch=1)
```